# Disable my nVidia video card driver in Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, nvidia-graphics-card, xen

I'm trying to passthrough my `nv` video card to my `domU`, but I could not bind my video card to the `pciback` driver

I only have one video card with the pci number `0000:03:00.0`, so I used the following command

```
echo -n "0000:03:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nouveau/bind
```

to unbind the `nouveau` driver from my video card.

The screen went black because I have forcefully removed the video driver, therefore I `ssh`'d into the computer to run further commands

I ran:

```
echo -n "0000:03:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pciback/bind
```

to try to bind it to my `pciback driver`, but I got:

```
bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

I found out that this was the message shown when trying to bind a PCI device which is already bound. Therefore, I think that something was still using my video card

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your first step, echoing the ID into /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nouveau/bind is wrong.  You need to echo it into nouveau/unbind, then in the pciback directory you need to echo the ID into new_slot, then bind.